# Special characters in CSV Python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, encoding

Excel is not correctly producing the special characters after encoding. I tried encoding the excel file directly, as well as the text being inputted into the csv. I also tried changing the excel file to CSV UTF-8.I am using python 3 and mac os.

Here are pictures of the output in terminal and in excel: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljY5B.jpg

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

with open('text.txt', 'r') as fin:

    text = fin.read()
    lst = text.split("\n")


with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'w', encoding= 'UTF-8', newline='') as fout:
    headers = "English, Arabic, Chinese(simplified), Chinese(traditional, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Hebrew, Hindi, Irish, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Turkish\n"
    fout.write(headers)

    language_lst = ['en','ar','zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'fi', 'fr', 'de','el', 'iw', 'hi', 'ga', 'it', 'ja', 'ko', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'es', 'tr']
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        for i in language_lst:
            translated_text = translator.translate(item, dest = i)


            new = str(translated_text).split(",")[2].replace("text=","").strip()

            new_lst.append(new)


    counter = 0

    for z in new_lst:
        z.encode('utf-8')
        fout.write(z+ ',')
        counter += 1
        print(z)

        if counter % 19 == 0:
            fout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a gallery, post a link to individual pics. You don't have the permissions yet, but others can make the images show up in your question that way.

Comment: You don't need to prefix unicode strings with `u` in python 3; all strings are unicode by default.

Comment: @mooglinux Oops, thanks. I was trying to test everything and anything to get it to work.

Comment: Force `utf-8` encoding while importing your csv file into Excel, or create file with BOM as `with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'w', encoding= 'utf_8_sig', newline='') as fout:`

Comment: @JosefZ: awesome, I had the exact same issue with Polish text output and your suggestion fixed it. But is there a reason why so many people post answers in the comments? When searchig for topics in the question overview, it looks like there's no answer at all and people might not bother to check.

Comment: @OnceUponATime maybe we all are feeling ashamed that Excel isn't capable of recognizing UTF-8… and many pieces of software on Microsoft Windows such as Notepad or Excel treat the BOM as a required magic number rather than use heuristics. Weird, nowadays…